# SQL Setting column name as function from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code:

```
-- Create Function
if object_id('dbo.J_TRIM') is not null drop function dbo.J_TRIM
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.J_TRIM(@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@string)) AS [@string]
END
GO

SELECT dbo.J_TRIM(Supplier) FROM Supplier_List
```

It all works apart from when I try to set the column name as the string by using `AS [@string]`. Is this possible in SQL, and if so, how do I fix my code?

Comment: This is a scalar-valued function. It doesn't *have* a column name, it has an (unnamed) return value. If you want to assign a column name, that has to be done in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: Incidentally, a function like this will only give you grief. The optimizer is terrible with scalar-valued functions. You will get much better results either simply writing out `LTRIM(RTRIM(...))` every time or (if reusing the logic actually pays off, like it does not here) rewriting the function as an inline table-valued function. Unlearn what you know from languages actually designed for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this function supposed to be doing?  Functions return values, not values with names.  So, you can just do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.J_TRIM(@string VARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@string));
END;
GO
```

When you *call* the function, then you can give it an alias:

```
SELECT dbo.J_TRIM(Supplier) as Supplier
FROM Supplier_List ;
```